# Flutter Form Label Style in Theme Needs to have the same size when field has content and without a content

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-form-builder

Im trying to solve the following problem:

The label is too big:
[image: This is too big:]

And when the field has content -  the label size is OK but needs some padding at the bottom: [image]

I need to solve in in a theme level, since it applies to the whole application.
I would like to have both Label Text states with the same fontSize, and add some padding (contentPadding doesn't do the trick)

Is there a solution for this?

````
                    child: FormBuilderTextField(
                      name: 'age',
                      // initialValue: widget.mom.age,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: ('Age'),
                      ),
                      // valueTransformer: (text) => num.tryParse(text),
                      onChanged: (value) => widget.mom.age = value.toString(),
                      validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                        FormBuilderValidators.numeric(context),
                        FormBuilderValidators.max(context, 70),
                      ]),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ),```
````

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet of this field?

Comment: Added the code for this field

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found parameter: floatingLabelBehavior and updated the theme.
This has solved the problem, by not showing the label inside the input field, but always outside.

````
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think Using Focus node and style property of label and Textfield you can achieve your desired result

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidget createState() => _MyWidget();
}

class _MyWidget extends State<MyWidget> {
  
  String text = "";
  FocusNode focus = FocusNode();
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
        controller: _controller,
        onTap: (){
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);
        },
        focusNode: focus,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14,height: 1.6
          ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Add task...',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: focus.hasFocus || _controller.text.length >= 1 ? 19 : 14,
            fontWeight: focus.hasFocus ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal
          )
            ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've actually seen this approach. The issue here is that I need it for all the fields in the application, hence a Theme level solution

Comment: okay then why don't you just make it as a CustomWidget that you can use in the whole project?